# postgres sql - generate_series for date - how to do a WHERE condition on the date (has timezone)

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, where-clause, generate-series

I'ved got a postgres SQL query below on a generate_series of dates (with timezone since I want it timezone specific), and I would like to put a WHERE condition to filter based on a specific date. I have attempted with the following WHERE statement and it fails.

```
where d::date = "2020-11-21"
```

You can also test it out here my query - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b62dcd5f867a352645c0b2944a32a010

```
SELECT 
     d::date  AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Tokyo' AS created_date,  
     e.id,  
     e.name,
     e.division_id,
     MIN(a.created_at) FILTER (WHERE a.activity_type = 1) as min_time_in,
     MAX(a.created_at) FILTER (WHERE a.activity_type = 2) as max_time_out
FROM    (SELECT MIN(created_at), MAX(created_at) FROM attendance) AS r(startdate,enddate)
  , generate_series(
        startdate::timestamp, 
        enddate::timestamp, 
        interval '1 day') g(d)
    CROSS JOIN  employee e
    LEFT JOIN   attendance a ON a.created_at::date = d::date AND e.id = a.employee_id
    where d::date = "2020-11-21" <--- this is an error, how do I query on a specific date
GROUP BY 
    created_date
  , e.id
  , e.name
  , e.division_id
ORDER BY 
    created_date
  , e.id;
```

it complaints:

```
ERROR:  column "2020-11-21" does not exist
LINE 15:     where d::date = "2020-11-21"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double quotes stand for identifiers, while what you want is a literal date. You can phrase this using a standard literal date:

```
where d::date = date '2020-11-21'
```

Or with a Postgres cast:

```
where d::date = '2020-11-21'::date
```

If `d` has no time component, casting it is not necessary:

```
where d = date '2020-11-21'
```

And event if it does, you can still avoid the cast with a half-open filter:

```
where d >= date '2020-11-21' and d < date '2020-11-21' + interval '1 day'
```

Comment: btw, can I put a timezone in the date something like this also: where d::date = date '2020-11-21' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Tokyo'

Comment: @Axil: yes, you can.

Comment: it runs but nothing comes out from the query - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d883970e0e6003c6ab3c9adc320fdb7c

Comment: @Axil: probably, you want to filter without the time zone translation, and then display the translated date. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=26ec7798aa263b5e77d17cd88222a433

Comment: @Axil: You're now comparing a date with a timestamp, that won't match. Check this example: SELECT date '2020-11-20' = date '2020-11-20'  AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Tokyo' -- this results in a timestamp;